# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error. How do I solve this issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, python-requests

Below is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys

driver = webdriver.firefox()
driver.get ("http://www.python.org")
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/pselenium/sample.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.firefox()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I check the directory firefox is all lowercase and not "Firefox". I dont know whats the problem. I have even updated the browser.

Comment: You don't want the `firefox` module/package, you want the `Firefox` class.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox('./geckodriver')
```

By the way, besides installing the Selenium python package using pip you have to download the [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and pass its location to the Firefox class when initializing the driver.

The command for installing Selenium is this:

```
pip install -U selenium
```